# Segmenting users in OneSignal

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I have to add Push notifications in my app and OneSignal looks like a good option. But I have a few questions regarding creating User Segments:

1) If I create Segments with multiple custom tags, are the notifications sent to that segment sent to all those users who are subscribed to any of those tags or only those users who are subscribed to all the tags in that segment?

2) Is it a good idea to create many singleton segments(segments with a single tag) or it is a better idea to create specific segments with multiple tags that represent the topics that users should be subscribed to.

A little context information:

I am making a Notification System for my college and the idea is to deliver notifications to the students of a particular branch/class/year/course as needed. So one way I see it is to make a Segment for each kind of category, the final P&C would result in a lot of segments, so I am looking for a more logical way to adjust the segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. If I create Segments with multiple custom tags, are the notifications sent to that segment sent to all those users who are
>      subscribed to any of those tags or only those users who are subscribed
>      to all the tags in that segment?

The notification will be sent to users who have all of the tags in the segment. (An AND operation).

You can leverage multiple segments in order to get an OR operation between the segments.

> 2. Is it a good idea to create many singleton segments(segments with a single tag) or it is a better idea to create specific segments with
>      multiple tags that represent the topics that users should be
>      subscribed to.

It really depends on the use-case, as described above.

> I am making a Notification System for my college and the idea is to
>   deliver notifications to the students of a particular
>   branch/class/year/course as needed. So one way I see it is to make a
>   Segment for each kind of category, the final P&C would result in a lot
>   of segments, so I am looking for a more logical way to adjust the
>   segments.

If you're sending notifications through the OneSignal API, you can use the "filters" field to dynamically target users based on various criteria. However for sending messages through the OneSignal dashboard it does seem like you will need to create many segments.